# Iron MQ REST API in Sharepoint Workflow

Tags: sharepoint, ironmq

I am trying to call an Iron MQ Rest API in a sharepoint workflow.

Here are the API details :
http://dev.iron.io/mq/reference/api/#add_messages_to_a_queue

I am not able to find a way to pass request body when using Call HTTP Web Service action in my workflow.

The API is expecting a request body in the following format :

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "body": "This is my message 1."
    },
    {
      "body": "This is my message 2.",
      "timeout": 30,
      "delay": 2,
      "expires_in": 86400
    }
  ]
}
```

Request parameters are accepted as dictionary in sharepoint. But the above content needs to be provided in the request body. This is usually done using the -d parameter in Curl.

What is the equivalent of this in Sharepoint Call HTTP Web Service Action ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by using an alternative API provided by IronMQ.

http://dev.iron.io/mq/reference/api/#add_messages_to_a_queue_via_webhook